# Queria exibir a arrow function, neste caso é possível ? coloco alí embaixo objeto.exibirResumo(x ) e não vai

Tags: javascript

let nome = 'Matheus'
let idade = 18
let sexo = 'Masculino'
let profissao = 'programador'

```
        let objeto = {
            nome: nome, //'Matheus' aparecerá
            idade: idade,
            sexo: sexo,
            profissao: profissao,
            exibirResumo: x => {
                console.log(`${this.nome}, ${this.idade} anos, ${this.sexo} é ${this.profissao}`)
            }
        }


        console.log(objeto)
        objeto.exibirResumo(x)
```

Comment: 1) Você tenta passar `x` na chamada da função, mas `x` não existe. 2) Arrow functions não possuem referência a `this`, apenas herdam o `this` do contexto mais acima, se houver. Ou seja, não podem ser usadas como métodos. Utilize uma função comum na declaração do objeto.

Answer (score -3):

Não podemos usar arrow functions em objetos, arrow functions não tem o this, e esse parametro x ai seu não estava fazendo muito sentido, abaixo segue um exemplo que funciona:

```js
let objeto = {
  nome: "Lucas",
  idade: 24,
  sexo: "masculino",
  profissao: "programador",
  exibirResumo: function() {
    console.log(`${this.nome}, ${this.idade} anos, sexo ${this.sexo} é ${this.profissao}`)
  }
}

objeto.exibirResumo()
```